# What's the number of ways Lior can eat 4 fruits with conditions?

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

I would appreciate if you could help me understand how to get a correct final answer.
. Below, I described the question and my attempt to solve it.

- A friend from class told me the answer is $f(n) = 3f(n-1)-f(n-2)-f(n-3)$.
- I try two different ways to approch this problem.  In none of them I get the answer I mentioned above.

  - In "Way 1" I don't know how to solve the recursive formula.
  - In "Way 2"  I get a different recursive formula for $f(n)$.

### Question

> Lior eats $4$ different fruits every day. The fruits are: Banana, strawberry, apple and orange.
>  Lior will never eat two bananas in a row, she will never eat two oranges in a row, and after an apple she will only eat an apple.
>  
> Suppose that on a certain day she eats $n$ fruits. $f(n)$ denote the different ways Lior can eat fruits on this day. Find a recursive formula for $f(n)$

### Way 1

"Banana" $=0$ , "Strawberry"$=1$, "Apple" $=2$ and "orange" $=3$.

$(a_1 ,a_2 ,\dots ,a_n )$ describes the order in which Lior ate the fruits.

$f_i(n)$ denote the number of different ways Lior ate fruits s.t $(a_1 ,a_2 ,\dots ,a_{n-1},i )$

$f_0(n) = f_1(n-1)+f_3(n-1) $

$f_1(n) = f_0(n-1)+f_1(n-1)+f_3(n-1) $

$f_2(n) = f_0(n-1)+f_1(n-1)+f_2(n-1)+f_3(n-1) =  f(n-1)$

$f_3(n) = f_0(n-1)+f_1(n-1)$

I don't know how to continue from here.

### Way 2

"Banana" $=0$ , "Strawberry"$=1$, "Apple" $=2$ and "orange" $=3$.

$(a_1 ,a_2 ,\dots ,a_n )$ describes the order in which Lior ate the fruits.

$g_i(n)$ denote the number of different ways Lior ate fruits s.t $(i ,a_2 ,\dots ,a_{n-1},a_n )$

$f_0(n) = g_1(n-1)+g_2(n-1)+g_3(n-1) $

$f_1(n) = g_0(n-1)+g_1(n-1)+g_2(n-1)+g_3(n-1)= f(n) $

$f_2(n) = g_2(n-1)= 1$

$f_3(n) =  g_0(n-1)+g_1(n-1)+g_2(n-1)$

From this I get $f(n) = 3f(n-1)+2 \ne 3f(n-1)-f(n-2)-f(n-3) $

Comment: An obvious first step is to compute $f(n)$ for several values of $n$.  At least that should distinguish between some of the proposed recursions.

Comment: Way 1 works. Given that you "know" the recurrence, verify it. If you didn't know the recurrence, then like Lulu suggested, find enough small values so that you can guess at it. EG The $f(n) \approx 3f(n-1)$ should be apparent.  $\quad$ For way 2, how did you get $f(n) = 3f(n-1) + 2$? I got $f(n) = 3f(n-1) - g_0(n-1) - g_3(n-1) + 1$. Again, given that we "know" the recurrence, we can try to force it out. Otherwise, you can try to continue eliminating terms, like in a system of linear equations.

Comment: @CalvinLin  Thank you so much :)

Comment: @Lior why did you write $f_0{n}=g_1{(n-1)}+g_2{(n-1)}+g_3{(n-1)}$ instead of $g_0{n}=g_1{(n-1)}+g_2{(n-1)}+g_3{(n-1)}$. When you write  $f_0{n}=g_1{(n-1)}+g_2{(n-1)}+g_3{(n-1)}$, it is understood that the last digit is banana

Comment: @CalvinLin please look at my comment, i see that you also used mixed $f$ and $g$ in your comment

Comment: @NotaSalmonFish You are right to call out that the Way 2 expressions should be $g_i (n) = \ldots$. $\quad$ I did not mix $f_i, g_j$. I used $f(n)$ in Way 2, which based on the writeup, was assumed to be defined as per Way 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Way 1 and 2 works (other than the error in way 2). To proceed, you could either:

1. Given that you "know" the recurrence, verify it.
2. If you didn't know the recurrence, then like Lulu suggested, find enough small values so that you can guess at it
3. Alternatively, try to force it out like so for way 1:

$\begin{array}{l l l}f(n) & =&  f_0 (n) + f_1(n) + f_2(n) + f_3(n) \\
& = & 3f(n-1) + f_1(n-1) - 2f_2(n-1)     \\ 
& = & 3f(n-1) + [f_2(n-1) - f_2(n-2)] - 2f(n-2) \\ 
& = & 3f(n-1) + [f(n-2) - f(n-3)] - 2f(n-2)    \\ 
& = & 3f(n-1) - f(n-2) -f(n-3)    \\ 
\end{array}$

As for the explanation of each step, you've already made the necessary observations like $f_2(n) = f(n-1)$, so you should be able to work them through.

Comment: Thank you! you helped a lot with checking my answer and finding that error. Do you know where I can learn to sovle a system of linear recursive equations?

Comment: @Lior Donnaastor's comment about "characteristic equation of the matrix" is the correct way to go, but it does require a lot more theory. An analogy is saying "Solve simultaneous equations using the matrix representation" -> It's not absolutely needed, though it makes the solution essentially a one-liner if you know the theory.  $\quad$ Stretching that analogy, we can find the recurrence by elimination. EG We can get rid of $f_2 (n) = f(n-1)$, we get rid of $f_1(n) = f(n) - f_2(n) = f(n) - f(n-1)$.

Comment: Great. I understand what's you're saying. Thank you so much!